# How to format the order of first/last name and remove prefix and nickname

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to retrieve a hierarchy of managers and the column which stores the manager names for a given person are formatted like this `Smith, Mr. William (Bill)`. I want this output to simply be `William Smith`. So far I have put this together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(u.manager, LEN(u.manager)-(1+CHARINDEX(', ', u.manager))) + ' ' +
LEFT(u.manager, CHARINDEX(', ', u.manager) - 1) as ManagerName
FROM Users u
```

The current result from that query using my example above is `Mr. William (Bill) Smith`. This CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING stuff always gives me a lot of trouble so I am not really sure what the easiest way to do this is. This is also a one-off, so I am not sure a function would be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe45d/29)

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(manager,0,CHARINDEX(',', manager)) as surname,
  SUBSTRING(manager,CHARINDEX('. ', manager)+2, LEN(manager)-CHARINDEX(' (', manager)+1) as name,
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(manager,CHARINDEX('. ', manager)+2, LEN(manager)-CHARINDEX(' (', manager)+1),
         ' ',
          SUBSTRING(manager,0,CHARINDEX(',', manager))) as 'name surname'
FROM
  Users
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|   surname   |    name   | name surname |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
    Smith        William    William Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your query and modified a little bit:

```
SELECT
    ---this is the tricky part: inner part finds the first instance of '(' parenthesis 
     --and substract it from the length of the first name and get only the left part of the first name by subtracting it
    CONCAT (
        LEFT(t.FirstName, LEN(t.FirstName) - (LEN(t.FirstName) - CHARINDEX('(', t.FirstName) + 1))
        ,t.LastName
        )
FROM (
    --basically separating your above syntax to two columns
    SELECT RIGHT('Smith, Mr. William (Bill)', LEN('Smith, Mr. William (Bill)') - CHARINDEX('.', 'Smith, Mr. William (Bill)') - 1) AS FirstName
        ,LEFT('Smith, Mr. William (Bill)', CHARINDEX(', ', 'Smith, Mr. William (Bill)') - 1) AS LastName
    ) t
```

Here is the query that should work with your table name and column:

```
SELECT
    ---Use case when statement to determine if there are any instances of '(' in the first name
    CONCAT (
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('(', t.FirstName) > 0
            THEN LEFT(t.FirstName, LEN(t.FirstName) - (LEN(t.FirstName) - CHARINDEX('(', t.FirstName) + 1))
        ELSE t.FirstName + ' '
        END
    ,t.LastName
    )
FROM (
    SELECT 
    RIGHT(u.manager, LEN(u.manager) - CHARINDEX('.', u.manager) - 1) AS FirstName
    ,LEFT(u.manager, CHARINDEX(', ', u.manager) - 1) AS LastName from Users u
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RIGHT(NameStripped, LEN(NameStripped) - (1 + CHARINDEX(', ', NameStripped))) + ' ' + LEFT(NameStripped, CHARINDEX(', ', NameStripped) - 1) AS ManagerName --Your original code
FROM (
    SELECT replace(replace(
            LEFT(u.manager, CHARINDEX('(', u.manager) - 2) --Get rid of nickname
        , 'Mr. ', ''), 'Ms.', '') AS NameStripped --Get rid of Mr/Ms
    from MyTable u) a
```

This should work - I used the code you posted, but added a subquery to remove the nicknames and prefixes.

Note that you may need to adjust this if a) you have more prefix options than this (in which case you could add additional `replace`s) and/or b) not everyone in your database has a nickname (in which case you'll want to wrap that part in a case statement, most likely).

Comment: This wouldn't work if there is a prefix like Jr., Sr.,Dr.,etc.

Comment: @Nepali - I agree he'll need to add more replaces if the database contains other prefixes (see 2nd paragraph).  Since there was no info about what prefixes are in his data, and this is a one-off operation, I wrote for the most common two with the assumption that the poster could add others as needed.

Comment: @NepaliRookie  I wrote it as "replaces" rather than searching the string for the first period because some abbreviations are more commonly suffixes than prefixes (like Jr, Sr, PhD), and because it's possible that some entries into the database contain titles without a period in them, such as Miss.